# Python-requests, how to get login token

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to login to a URL and get info about the products on my cart. For the for data of the login request I need username and password, and also a token and a recaptcha response that I don't know how to get them. The token has the name "struts.token" and I am trying to get it through this code, but is not working.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'user-agent' : 'your user agent'
}

with requests.Session() as s:

    s.headers = headers
    r = s.get('https://www.lidl.es/es/account/login')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')
    token = soup.find('input', {'name' : 'struts.token'})['value']
    print(token)
```

When I inspect the elements and network through my browser I can find the token easily, but at the request response I can't. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do some sort of automation. Maybe 'Selenium' can help you with this issue.

Comment: modern pages use JavaScript to add items (and Recaptcha) but `requests`/`beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript - so first turn off JavaScript in browser and load url in browser to see if page can work without JavaScript. If it can't work then you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: @furas it is any request library that supports JavaScript? i want to do this without using selenium, only requests, i don't know if it would be possible.

Comment: all modules use `selenium` (directly or hidden with `headless mode`) or `WebKit` widget from framework `Qt` (which long time ago was used to create browsers Safari, Chrome, etc.). [requests_html](https://docs.python-requests.org/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) should automatically download and install `Chromium` when you `render()` page with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

if the token exists when you inspect elements on chrome but does not exist on the request text this means that you're request is being blocked by the website and its serving you a html page different from what your browser gets
inspect the browser get request to the website you're trying to access and change the headers of the request get to those of the browser get

a lot of websites will block requests that does not contain a referrer and a origin header